# Creating Python Active Resource object from json file

Tags: python, json

So for testing purposes, I am trying to create a python ActiveResource object from a json file (I want the object to have attributes from the json file). More specifically I am using the ShopifyResource from (https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_python_api), which extends the ActiveResource object.

I looked through the source code and found some functions that I thought would be of some use: 
(https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_python_api/blob/master/shopify/base.py)

```
from pyactiveresource.activeresource import ActiveResource
import shopify.mixins as mixins

class ShopifyResource(ActiveResource, mixins.Countable):
    _format = formats.JSONFormat

    def _load_attributes_from_response(self, response):
        if response.body.strip():
            self._update(self.__class__.format.decode(response.body))
```

where _update is from ActiveResource (https://github.com/Shopify/pyactiveresource/blob/master/pyactiveresource/activeresource.py)

```
    def _update(self, attributes):
        """Update the object with the given attributes.

        Args:
            attributes: A dictionary of attributes.
        Returns:
            None
        """
        if not isinstance(attributes, dict):
            return
        for key, value in six.iteritems(attributes):
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                klass = self._find_class_for(key)
                attr = klass(value)
            elif isinstance(value, list):
                klass = None
                attr = []
                for child in value:
                    if isinstance(child, dict):
                        if klass is None:
                            klass = self._find_class_for_collection(key)
                        attr.append(klass(child))
                    else:
                        attr.append(child)
            else:
                attr = value
            # Store the actual value in the attributes dictionary
            self.attributes[key] = attr
```

So then I tried to do the following:

```
order = Order()
with open("file.json")) as json_file:
    x = json.loads(json_file.read())
    order._update(x)
```

Where Order extends ShopifyResource (which extends ActiveResource). If am not mistaken x should be a dictionary, which is an approriate parameter for the _update() function.

Yet I get the following output:

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vineet/Documents/project/tests/test_sync.py", line 137, in testSaveOrder1
    self.getOrder()
  File "/home/vineet/Documents/project/tests/tests/test_sync.py", line 113, in getOrder
    order._update(x)
  File "/home/vineet/Documents/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyactiveresource/activeresource.py", line 962, in _update
    attr.append(klass(child))
  File "/home/vineet/Documents/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/shopify/base.py", line 126, in __init__
    prefix_options, attributes = self.__class__._split_options(attributes)
  File "/home/vineet/Documents/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyactiveresource/activeresource.py", line 466, in _split_options
    if key in cls._prefix_parameters():
  File "/home/vineet/Documents/project/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyactiveresource/activeresource.py", line 720, in _prefix_parameters
    for match in template.pattern.finditer(path):
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

I even tried the following:

```
 order._update(order._format.decode(json_file.read()))
```

But that didn't work since 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'.

Answer (score 0):

It seems You are worried if x has correct format.  Print it, and check.

Btw: And use

```
x = json.load(json_file)
```

instead of

```
x = json.loads(json_file.read())
```

Comment: I am trying to get the values in the json file to be attributes in the order object. The python active resource API makes an http request and then uses the json from the response to create the active resource object with the attributes coming from the json in the response. I am trying to emulate that.

Comment: You wrote "If am not mistaken x should be a dictionary, which is an appropriate parameter for the _update() function.".  It is true but not whole true. I has to be dictionary with specific data in it (to cooperate with REST serer). _update function is protected, so it not supposed to be used directly. This is probably the reason, why details of that function are not in documentation.

Comment: Yeah I understand. I ended up writing my own function to add attributes from json file. Thanks for your help!